# ServiceNow: Show/Hide System Properties on a Property page

Tags: servicenow

I have created some System properties, grouped properties in a categories and created a property page to display properties. Now i want show/hide one property on the basis of value of another on the page.

I want to show/hide properties on basis of below conditions. Please see below screenshot:

[image]

In the above screenshot, if logging level is set to 'warn', I want to show Logging Destination property, but if it is set to any value other than 'warn', I want to hide Logging Destination. Is this possible?

Comment: what kind of page are you using? jelly? angular? can you post the code? you can do this anyway.. I can help if you can show how your page is.

Comment: @SunilBN I have created a group of System properties and created a module to display them. It's not a UI page. I have created a category in https://xxxxx.service-now.com/sys_properties_category.do. Anyway, I confirmed this with ServiceNow people, its not possible. The solution mentioned by Vivek, it's not exposed by ServiceNow.

Comment: you can create a UI page which can do anything for you. I am also servicenow employee :D

Comment: I have built a custom integration with ServiceNow and I have a requirement to create a page on ServiceNow where user can provide the configuration parameters required for application. For example, application is making a outbound REST call from ServiceNow, so user need to configure endpoint url and credentials required to make the REST call. How can I achieve this using a UI page? I have to read those parameters in the script include and perform the business logic.

Comment: create a custom table and store all of those config parameters in that table. And in script include, you can read those and perform the business logic.

Comment: we want customer to configure/modify this using the Properties page of our custom application. We can't use tables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that at the normal view without some nasty UI Script. Perhaps it's doable with the newer look of properties which you e.g. finds under Service Catalog->Catalog Administration->Properties

then another option is to build this with a Portal page and make the magic there, but not sure it will be worth the effort of doing.

Comment: Vivek, I went through the Properties page on Service Catalog. How to create that? I have posted the same question on Community forum here - https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=ac134046db025f802e247a9e0f9619be. I checked the Module for Properties and I can't understand the Arguments mentioned there.